# Solve $2^k \equiv 5 \pmod{577}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show there is no $k$ such that $2^k \equiv 5 \pmod{577}$.

My solution: (everything is modulo $577$)

$577$ is a prime with $\phi(577)=576=2^6 \cdot 3^2$.
First show that order of $2$ is $144$:
Note that $2^{576/2^2}\equiv 1$ but $2^{576/2^3}\not\equiv1$ and $2^{576/3}\not\equiv1$,
it follows that order of $2$ is $576/2^2=144$.

We conclude that if $2^{k}\not\equiv 5$ for $1<k<144$
then $2^{k}\not\equiv 5$ for any $k$. Now we have to compute $2^{k} \pmod {577}$ for $9<k<144$; lower bound is $9$ since $2^9=512<577$.

The problem with this is the line: now we have to compute $2^{k} \pmod {577}$ for $9<k<144$.

Is there a better method that avoids trying so many possibilities?

**Edit**:
Following the comment made to the accepted solution: If order of $2$ is not divisible by order of $5$, there is no solution. This may not be obvious but it is true. Multiplicative order of $5$ is $576$ since $5^{576/2}\not\equiv 1$ and $5^{576/3}\not\equiv 1$. Since $576$ does not divide $144$, there is no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Quadratic Reciprocity at your disposal, you can compute

$$\left(5\over577\right)=\left(577\over5\right)=\left(2\over5\right)=-1$$

Also, $577\equiv1$ mod $8$ implies

$$\left(2\over577\right)=1$$

which implies

$$\left(2^k\over577\right)=\left(2\over577\right)^k=1$$

so $5$ cannot be congruent to $2^k$ mod $577$ for any $k$.

**Added later**:  If Quadratic Reciprocity is not available (and indeed, the OP indicates that even the Legendre symbol is in the next chapter of the book they're working from), I don't see any alternative to doing a fair amount of computation.  Nonetheless, one happy coincidence makes it possible to keep the computations here manageable.  So here's a proof that $5$ can't be of the form $2^k$ mod $577$ with almost all the gory computational details:

First, let's compute some powers of $2$ mod $577$.

$$\begin{align}
2^2&=4\\
2^4&=4^2=16\\
2^8&=16^2=256\\
2^{16}&=256^2=65536\equiv335\\
2^{32}&\equiv335^2=112225\equiv287\\
2^{64}&\equiv287^2=82369\equiv435\\
\end{align}$$

At this point we can compute

$$2^{72}=2^{64}\cdot2^8\equiv435\cdot256=111360\equiv-1$$

On the other hand,

$$\begin{align}
5^2&=25\\
5^4&=25^2=625\equiv48=2^4\cdot3\\
\end{align}$$

That's our happy coincidence, because

$$5\equiv2^k\implies3\equiv2^{4(k-1)}\implies3^{18}\equiv2^{72(k-1)}\equiv(-1)^{k-1}$$

and we can now compute

$$\begin{align}
3^2&=9\\
3^4&=9^2=81\\
3^8&=81^2=6561\equiv214\\
3^{16}&\equiv214^2=45796\equiv213\\
\end{align}$$

hence

$$3^{18}=3^{16}\cdot3^2\equiv213\cdot9=1917\equiv186\not\equiv\pm1$$

There might be some other happy coincidence that allows for any even terser proof, but I suspect it'd take a lot of work (or luck) to find one.  The take-home message, I'd say, is that Quadratic Reciprocity is an extremely powerful theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't gotten that far yet. That is the next chapter. But I'll accept your answer (after I read the chapter and understand your answer)

Comment: @mhp, fair enough.  May I ask what book you're using?  Perhaps what the current chapter wants you to do is compute the order of $2$ (which you've done), the order of $5$, and note that the latter doesn't divide the former, which it would have to do if $5$ were a power of $2$ mod $577$.

Comment: The book I'm reading is an old edition by David Burton. The problem in the post is not from the book. I just made that up. But I understand your comment and have marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have an old edition of Burton myself which I just took a look at, so I can see where you're coming from.  It's maybe worth noting that until he gets to quadratic reciprocity, Burton rarely mentions any explicit prime with more than two digits; his early examples and exercises are all small enough that it's not a great burden to compute everything you need by hand.